# Echoing session variables in php

Tags: php, session-variables, syntax-error

I know that in php I can put a variable name inside a quoted string when I use echo, but I apparently can't do this with a session variable.  Can anyone explain why?

Here is the code, with the "offending" php commented out:

```
<?php
session_start();
$test = 100;
$_SESSION['test'] = 200;
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <p><?php echo($test."<br />");?></p>
  <p><?php echo("$test"."<br />");?></p>
  <p><?php echo($_SESSION['test']."<br />");?></p>
  <p><?php //echo("$_SESSION['test']"."<br />");?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

And the output looks like this:

```
100

100

200
```

But if I uncomment the offending code line:

```
  <p><?php echo("$_SESSION['test']"."<br />");?></p>
```

I get no output and the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in - on line 14
```

So I can go on my merry way knowing how to do it correctly (just keep the session variable outside of the double quotes), but I would really like to understand why this doesn't work for session variables.

Thanks!

Comment: Please read the PHP manual about strings: http://php.net/strings, use `{$var}` instead.

Comment: Thanks... I had read that page, but re-read after your comment and realized there was a link I should have followed on that page to another that had the explanation.  Sorry for asking something so trivial. :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Inside a double-quoted string you must enclose a complex variable (array or object property) in `{}`:

```
<p><?php echo("{$_SESSION['test']}"."<br />");?></p>
```

This isn't an issue with `$_SESSION` specifically, but any array accessed by quoted keys.  Note, that you *can* include a numerically indexed array value with wrapping in `{}`, as in `"echo $array[2] is two";`